# How do I access a SQL Database made from a file with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

First off, let me say that I'm new to SQL and PHP, so don't hurt my feelings too much, ok? :)

In `table.sql`, I put

```
CREATE TABLE `quill-members` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment
    `user` varchar(32) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL default '',
    `password` varchar(32) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL default '',
    `email` varchar(255) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL default '',
    `regIP` varchar(15) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL default '',
    `dt` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
    UNIQUE KEY `user` (`user`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

In a file called `login.php`, I have a two forms, one that the user fills out to sign up, the other that the user fills out to sign in.  The sign in form will go to a page named something like `login.php` that processes the information, logs the user in if the credentials are correct, and sends them back to `login.php` with an error message if their credentials are wrong.  The other form will send the information to a file called something like `signup.php` and will sign the user up and send him/her to their account page/home page, either or.

My question is, how do I access the table "quill-members" from the PHP scripts, if that's possible, and, if not, how I would go about doing this.

I would also like to know if the table made in `table.sql` will save or not when the user closes the webpage.  My guess is no, so if it doesn't save, how do I make it save?  I'm using godaddy.com, so if I can set a database up there and access it, that would be good to know too.

Comment: Sidenote; `password varchar(32)` - That suggests you're using MD5 to store passwords with, and is considered no longer safe to use. Set it to 60+ and use `password_hash()`. That's if you intend on going live with this.

Comment: This question is too broad, given what you're asking. To answer this to a certain extent; you can access that database with php, sure. You should visit the php.net website and look up some tutorials and using a prepared statement and a safe password hashing function.

Comment: Thanks, I might try that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a table definition written down doesn't automatically generate a table. You'll have to create a database first, then create the table in the database, connect to the database from within PHP, and then write functions to operate on the database from within PHP.

I suggest following some tutorials on PHP and MySQL. [This W3Schools tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp) might be a good starting point.

Comment: As a side note: [NEVER STORE PASSWORDS IN PLAIN TEXT](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/120540/why-shouldnt-i-store-passwords-in-plaintext)

Comment: ^ that sidenote: They're not using plaintext, they're using MD5 http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php *Returns the hash as a 32-character hexadecimal number.* - which their password column length of 32 clearly shows.

Comment: You should go over their question again and read it in its entirety. There's much more at stake here than what you posted in your answer. Plus, a "Stack pro tip": It's best to reference the official manuals from both PHP.net and MySQL.com if you're going to just place a link. Some really don't like W3Schools and that may attract downvotes.

Comment: Thank you, that was what I was looking for.